# C# Generic Type Get Minimum Date

Tags: c#, generics, lambda

I have a List of object with Generic Type (List myGenericList), and I know there's a property "Date" (type DateTime) in the generic type.

I would like to get the minimum date, something like this:
myGenericList.Min(r=>r.Date);

Here's what I implemented, but the code below gives an error:

```
 - 'List<T>' does not contain a definition for 'Min' and the best
   extension method overload 'Queryable.Min<T, DateTime>(IQueryable<T>,
   Expression<Func<T, DateTime>>)' requires a receiver of type
   'IQueryable<T>' myGenericList
```

code:

```
    internal DateTime GetMinimumDate()
    {
        Expression<Func<T, DateTime>> lambdaExpression = ConstructLambdaExpression();
        return myGenericList.Min(lambdaExpression);
    }

    private Expression<Func<T, DateTime>> ConstructLambdaExpression()
    {
        //construct lambda expression: r => r.Date
        var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var propertyOrFieldExpression = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameterExpression, "Date");
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, DateTime>>(propertyOrFieldExpression,parameterExpression);

    }
```

Do you have any ideas?
Thank you!

Regards,
Léona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `Expression<Func<T, DateTime>>` to `Func<T, DateTime>`

The `Min` Function for `List` (Actually`IEnumerable`) accepts a `Func` and not an `Expression`. This is the error you're getting.

**Working Code:**

```
internal DateTime GetMinimumDate<T>(List<T> myGenericList)
{
    Func<T, DateTime> lambdaExpression = ConstructLambdaExpression<T>();
    return myGenericList.Min(lambdaExpression);
}

static Func<T, DateTime> ConstructLambdaExpression<T>()
{
    PropertyInfo dateProperty = typeof(T).GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Date");
    return t => Convert.ToDateTime(dateProperty.GetValue(t));
}
```